# Is it possible to read the inputs from a text file for an application installation in Linux?

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install one application in my Linux box.
This installation asks for few manual inputs like root username, password and few yes/no options.

I want to store these inputs in a text file so that the same can be read from it instead of waiting for manual inputs.

Can anyone please share some insights on how to achieve this?

Comment: Is the installer a GUI or a CLI? What do the prompts look like?

Comment: @muru - It is a CLI.

Answer (score 0):

For a cli you can run your command once with

```
autoexpect command args...
```

and interact with it as usual with the answers wanted.  When this ends you will have an executable file `script.exp` which is an **expect** script (install the `expect` and `tcl` packages). You can run it at any time to repeat the command and have the same answers provided.  The file is easily edited in a text editor to slightly modify an answer.  You can write your own such scripts to do more complex interactions. See the `expect` man page.